# Imam shows awrah during prayer validity of Salaah?

Tags: salat, fiqh, awrah, imam-al-jamaah

If a member of the congregation sees the awrah of the Imam such as when he is bending in sujood and his back is exposed what should he do? Should he say STOP! And explain why there and then or until the end? Does all the congregation have to repeat with the imam if possible.